# How to add indepth environment variables in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-apps

I am trying to add my context as an `environment variable` in `Azure Container App` like below but it throws an error.

```
az containerapp update -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup -v ConnectionStrings:MyContext=secretref:mycontextsecretkey
```

> Invalid value: "ConnectionStrings:MyContext": Invalid Environment
> Variable Name

I tried with `ConnectionStrings__MyContext` but the Asp.Net Core app does not recognize it.

How can I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error **Invalid value: "ConnectionStrings:MyContext"**: Invalid Environment Variable Name indicates that environment variable you are trying to define is unsupported.

Instead of using **"ConnectionStrings:MyContext", use MyConnectionStrings_MyContext** as your environment variable.

You can use the below command,

```
az containerapp update -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup -v MyConnectionStrings_MyContext=secretref:mycontextsecretkey
```

Reference : [Set Environment variables to Azure Container App | Miha Jakovac](https://www.mihajakovac.com/set-environment-variables-to-azure-container-app/)

Comment: I tried with `MyConnectionStrings_MyContext` and `MyConnectionStrings__MyContext` but no use.

Comment: @Ramesh Are you able to update the environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I can add but those env variables are not effective where as other env variables without `.` are effective.

Comment: @Ramesh, Could you please follow the [document](https://www.mihajakovac.com/set-environment-variables-to-azure-container-app/) and try!!

Comment: Exactly... but no luck for me. The same image with `__` environment variables is working in the case of `Azure Web Apps for Containers`.